# Python 3.9.1 errors when attempting to import sqlite3

Tags: python, windows, sqlite

Please note that I am using pure Python and not something like Anaconda. Running on a new, updated Windows 10 machine with no virtual environment. After removing all previous Python installations, rebooting and performing a fresh install if Python 3.9.1. I run the python console and type:
import sqlite3

I receive the following error:
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import sqlite3
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\sqlite3_*init*_.py", line 23, in 
> > > from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
> > > File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
> > > from _sqlite3 import *
> > > ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified module could not be found.

I verified that the sqlite3.dll file does exist in C:\Program Files\Python39\DLLs

Answer (score 0):

It was an environment issue. Previous builds (using Kivy) had left .pyd and .pyc files in the application directory and when we ran the application, python would try to load those and the files they reference, rather than using the proper files in the Python39 directory. As soon as we deleted those artifacts, the app ran fine (and sqlite loaded fine).